# Ubuntu 20.04 How do I stop the "Press ESC for Boot OPtions/Settings" from appearing

Tags: boot, 20.04

I have tried every answer I have found on Ask Ubuntu and other sites and NONE of them have worked. I am trying to run 20.04 at a junior high school but need to disable the message and/or the ability to get into boot menu, so the students don't wreck havoc on the computers.

Comment: You cannot do that from Ubuntu. That's baked into the hardware by the manufacturer.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Modern BIOS has an admin password. Your students may not get in, if you set it..

Comment: I have not found any options for that on the laptops we are attempting this on.